# Ember Dirty check validation in model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember has provided hasDirtyAttributes property in model in order to check a model has dirty value or not

My question is, if model has hasMany or belongsTo relations, how can we validation dirty check? any best approach to do that.

Comment: I think `belong_to` may not response to the dirty check but `has_many` may have. I would also like to know the answer.

Comment: It doesn't. You have to check it by hand. `belongsTo('foo')` is easy. Just check `model.foo.hasDirtyAttributes`. You can basically do the same for `hasMany` with a bit of array work.

Comment: I do something which I don't consider a best practice, but I created an observer on the property that keeps the child collection something like `prop@each.hasDirtyAttributes` and then i check if any of them has dirty attrs but it's kind of expensive